# Eclipse doesnt update .java files

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a little java project which is build in gradle. I imported the project to eclipse. The gradle task run starts the server and run the application in localhost(using Tomcat). Problem is, how to refresh my .java data instead of re-run the application always again. This takes time. I can change my .jsp files in build directory and after page refreshing data changes. But problem is .java files. In gradle there are task install which compile the whole project(shows errors if have), but the page content doesnt change, so i have to run project again to see the changes.

I have .class-es in 2 places. In build directory and exploded/WEB-INF. IMO, if application runs, it is using build directory files, but i dont know what files are in WEB-INF directory...

Answer (score 1):

Redeployment has always been a great time consumer. There are a couple of tools(some comercial) that will help you, like JRebel. If you want to use Netbeans, there is a deploy on save option too. I don't know any other options, I'm sure there are a few more, but anyway, this should be a good start.

Comment: JRebel works fine with NetBeans too. BTW, Deploy on Save feature might cause the full re-deployment of the app, which takes time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to start your application with debugger flags, then every time you update and compile your source code, the JVM will pick-up a new version automatically, without redeployment, it is called "hot-swapping".

You will need to add something similar to your run task:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Then attach Eclipse debugger to `localhost:5005` and you will be good to go. It will not work if you are changing method signatures, add new class attributes or constants. Apply your changes within existing methods, then once everything works as expected, refactor and restart.

More information on debugging with Eclipse: [Debugging With Eclipse Platform](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/)